# Twitter Bootstrap Modal trigger on table click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

Folks, trying to follow example here `http://jsfiddle.net/yF45N/`.  I have JADE file below, which should open up a modal once a table item is clicked.  What am I missing?

Thanks!!!!

```
block Content

    if (pendingArray)

        legend Pending Requests
        table.table-hover.table-condensed
            thead
                tr
                    th id
                    th Email
                    th foo
                    th bar

            tbody
                - each val in pendingArray
                    tr 
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-id="#{val.id}"
                        data-target="#orderModal"
                        href='someModal'
                        td #{val.id}
                        td #{val.Email}
                        td #{val.foo}
                        td #{val.bar}

        orderModal.modal.fade
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
                    h4.modal-title Title
                .modal-body
                    p body
                .modal-footer
                    button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Save changes
body
    script.

        $(function(){
            $('#orderModal').modal({
                keyboard: true,
                backdrop: "static",
                show:false,

            }).on('show', function(){
                  var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
                //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
                $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow  + '</b>'))
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, even for a front-end idiot like myself:

```
    tbody
       - each val in pendingArray
          tr(data-toggle='modal', href='#mvrDisplayModal', data-target="#foo")
              td #{val.email}
              td #{val.blah}


#mvrDisplayModal.modal.fade
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') &times;
                    h4.modal-title Title
                .modal-body
                    p body
                    p #{foo}
                .modal-footer
                    button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Save changes
```